# Direct invocation vs indirect invocation in C

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, invocation, indirection

I am new to C and I was reading about how pointers "point" to the address of another variable. So I have tried indirect invocation and direct invocation and received the same results (as any C/C++ developer could have predicted). This is what I did:

```
int cost;
int *cost_ptr;

int main()
{
    cost_ptr = &cost;                          //assign pointer to cost
    cost = 100;                                //intialize cost with a value
    printf("\nDirect Access: %d", cost);
    cost = 0;                                  //reset the value
    *cost_ptr = 100;
    printf("\nIndirect Access: %d", *cost_ptr);
    //some code here

    return 0;                                  //1
}
```

**So I am wondering if indirect invocation with pointers has any advantages over direct invocation or vice-versa?** Some advantages/disadvantages could include speed, amount of memory consumed performing the operation (most likely the same but I just wanted to put that out there), safeness (like dangling pointers) , good programming practice, etc.
<sup>1</sup>Funny thing, I am using the GNU C Compiler (gcc) and it still compiles without the return statement and everything is as expected. Maybe because the C++ compiler will automatically insert the return statement if you forget.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: "So I am wondering if indirect invocation with pointers has any advantages over direct invocation and vice-versa."

Comment: I added an actual question mark to it..

Comment: Pointers are not magic. If you understand what is going on when you use a pointer, you should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: BTW-- "invocation" is not the same as "accessing". The former is appropriate when calling code, the latter for any kind of use. IN this case you probably wanted "access".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indirect and direct invocation are used in different places. In your sample the direct invocation is prefered. Some reasons to use pointers:

- When passing a large data structure to a function one can passa pointer instead of copying the whole data structure.
- When you want a function to be able to *modify* a variable in the calling function you have to pass a pointer to the original variable. If you pass it by value the called function will just modify a copy.
- When you don't know exactly which value you want to pass at compile time, you can set a pointer to the right value during runtime.
- When dynamically allocating a block of memory you have to use pointers, since the storage location is not known until runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer notation involves two memory fetches (or one fetch and one write) where the direct invocation involves one.

Since memory accesses are slow (compared to computation in registers; fast compared to access on disk), the pointer access will slow things down.

However, there are times when only a pointer allows you to do what you need.  Don't get hung up on the difference and *do* use pointers when you need them.  But avoid pointers when they are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the "printf(..., *cost) case, the value of "cost" is copied to the stack.  While trivial in this instance, imagine if you were calling a different function and "cost_ptr" pointed to a multi-megabyte data structure.

Comment: There is no "stack" in C, refer to such terms by their equivalent storage duration, i.e automatic in this case.